# variable = term compound prolog

Tags: prolog

Is it possible in prolog to do an assignment like Variable = TermCompound?

For example: X = token (a, b, c).

And, if you can do it, from X is it possible to derive the arguments and the functor of the compound term?

Comment: There is no assignment in Prolog. The variable `X` is unified (if possible) to `token (a, b, c)`. Nonetheless, yes, you can.

Comment: Thanks. And, after the unification, how can i extract from X the name of main functor, eg. 'token'?

Answer (score 3):

See your Prolog system documentation on the ISO standard predicates `=/2`, `functor/3`, `=../2`, and `arg/3`. Sample calls:

```
| ?- X = token(a, b, c).

X = token(a,b,c)

yes
| ?- X = token(a, b, c), functor(X, Name, Arity). 

Arity = 3
Name = token
X = token(a,b,c)

yes
| ?- X = token(a, b, c), X =.. [Name| Arguments].      

Arguments = [a,b,c]
Name = token
X = token(a,b,c)

yes
| ?- X = token(a, b, c), arg(2, X, Argument).    

Argument = b
X = token(a,b,c)

yes
```